# Enforce https + remove www + redirect aliases to main domain name on Apache 2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

Client site uses several domains leading to the same content, which is bad for SEO ("duplicated content").
example.com, www.example.com, foo.com, foo.example.com, www.foo.com and www.foo.example.com

Also, the site must now use https on all requests.

So the task now is to enforce the sole use of https://foo.example.com as the SSL certificate is for *.example.com. All other domains should be redirected to https://foo.example.com

I'm trying to implement these requirements via url rewriting in the website's root folder  .htaccess file.

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works, except for one use case: http://example.com

Requests pointing to http://example.com/hello do not get rewritten to the https://example.com.

So I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But i get a "redirection loop" error. It means the conditions are always true, but why?

**server details**

Server: LAMP (Apache 2) on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5

## UPDATE

I think my rewriting rules are correct, the issue  occurs upstream. System administrator informed me that their network redirects 443 requests to the local machine's :80 port. Also, phpinfo() on a https url shows no presence of SSL flags ( HTTPS= on does not appear in phpinfo()).

Comment: Try this line for ssl check: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]`. Otherwise, i don't see anything wrong

Comment: thank you, but same: it leads to a redirection loop. In the meanwhile, I've talked to the sysadmin: they redirect 443 to 80 inside the local network. So my virtualhost definitions have to use :80. Could it cause the issue?

Comment: That's certainly the cause of your loop

Comment: Could i tell my server to assign 80 instead of 443 for SSL ?

Comment: You should be able to do it by modifying `httpd.conf`. See this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A95431_01/install/ssl.htm#623513

Comment: Is there a way i could check if the request url contains 'http' instead of 'https' ?

Comment: Since your ssl port is 80, i don't see any way of determinate if it's http or https (in htaccess using http_host or server_port) except doing it in server-side with php for example

Comment: That's an idea, but how can i get the "https" part of the url? It does not appear in $_SERVER apparently...

Comment: Once again, i don't see any good way for this. The better is to keep port 80 for http and port 443 for ssl and ask your sysadmin not to redirect 443 to 80

Comment: thank you for your help. I've reported my situation to the sysadmin and will wait for him to act.

Comment: Quick point: it's probably preferable not to use `301` when you're trying out your rules, since the browser may remember the redirections from one config attempt to another (you might not actually see the effects of the actual configuration you're trying). Even if somehow the network redirects everything from 443 to 80 (a bit odd...), your browser shouldn't accept whatever redirection on the network makes it go from HTTPS to HTTP on that host (that's effectively a downgrade attack): it should warn about a bad certificate at the very least.

Comment: thanks for the 301 info. Just to be clear, the redirection fromm 443 to 80 happens internally, inside the datacenter network. It does not trigger the browser bad certificate warning, as I had to enforce the use of foo.example.com, since the certificate is on example.com domain name. I'll update my question (just in case) accordingly.

Comment: Can you clarify how this 443->80 works, where it happens? Are there reverse proxy servers along the way, and where is your configuration in all this?

Comment: I'm not sure, it happens upstream. The server i'm responsible for sits inside a network. I know that it is via Reverse Proxy, though. My config is really a standard LAMP setup. The issue was solved today by the sysadmin. Thank you for your help.